# Recommended software problems

Tags: software-installation, pi-400

I've just started exploring the Raspberry Pi 400 and I'm getting an error updating package data when I click Recommended software under preferences...
E:Repository 'http://rasbian.raspberrypi.org/rasbian buster InRealease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'olstable' W: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details

Any ideas of what to do?

Comment: yes, do what it suggests in the last sentence

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Comment: @jsotola Haven't used the Raspbian default desktop, but I'd guess that "clicking Recommended software under preferences" may show apt errors that don't make sense in that context, eg., WRT "This must be accepted explicitly...", then there is no way to do such a thing through the GUI (= an oversight). @ Steve To be fair that man page really doesn't address this in any obvious way.

Comment: @astroroots From a command-line try `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.  Hopefully this will provide you the means to "explicitly accept" the change, which is just about buster becoming oldstable, which is correct.  However, if you've really "just started" with the Pi you might instead consider installing the latest version of the OS, the one you have right now is not that.

Comment: Sweet ! Thanks @goldilocks. That was the trick. I just had to answer "y" twice for it to fully download I guess. Yeah, I wasn't sure how to access "manpage"